# Hide pop-up when click somewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two div's, and inside this two div's i have `<a href>` that invoce javascript function.
My problem is, when i click somewhere outside my form should hide that hide, for the second div..this is working, but for the first isnt.

HTML that have javascript to invoce:

```
<div id="joinUs">
<a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('joinusLogin'))">
        Join us!
</div>

<div id="invite">
    <a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('inviteNowSignup'))">
        <img src="/www/assets/newImages/header/Invite.png"></img>
</div>
```

HTML that have div's that is going to be invoced:

```
<div id="inviteNowSignup">
    <div id="backgroundSignup"></div>
    </a>
    <form id="signupForm">
        <input id="signupFormFields" type="email" name="email" placeholder=" E-mail"><br />
        <input id="signupFormFields" type="text" name="name" placeholder=" Password"><br />
        <input id="signupFormFields" type="text" name="subject" placeholder=" User Name"><br />
        <input id="submitSignup" type="submit" value="SIGN UP">
    </form>

    <div id="alreadyMember">
        Already a member? Log in here.
    </div>
</div>

<div id="joinusLogin">
    <div id="backgroundJoinus"></div>
    </a>
    <form id="loginForm">
        <input id="loginFormFields" type="email" name="email" placeholder=" E-mail"><br />
        <input id="loginFormFields" type="text" name="name" placeholder=" Password"><br />
        <input id="submitLogin" type="submit" value="LOG IN">
    </form>

    <div id="signupNow">
        Don't have an account yet? Sign up here.
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my Javascript function:

```
function hideshow(which){
if (!document.getElementById)
    return
if (which.style.display=="block")
    which.style.display="none"
else
    which.style.display="block"
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Is this your production code? If so, you should try closing the "a"-tags.

Comment: @SebastianG.Marinescu i have a tag close right after background div

Comment: That's not where you should be closing your a tag...you should close the a tags right after the "Join us!" and the img tag.

Comment: You also need semicolons after each statement in your hideshow function....three in total

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob i have 2 a tags closed, in my code. If i close a after my image, the function will only work if i click in the image..not in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest way to do that

add event to the `body` on click hide all pop-ups

```
$('body').click(function(){
   $('your-pop-up').hide();
});
```

then add `stopPropagation()` to this pop-ups to prevent hide when click inside it.

```
$('your-pop-up').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Now if you press any where outside your pop-ups thy will hide

Comment: I added both codes. The body event, is working fine..but the stoppropagation isnt working. When i click inside my form, the pop-up div hide

Comment: 1-make sure you write it in `capital P`  and if there is any input inside put stopPropagation to these input too.


2- if the pop-up inside container div make the stopPropagation to the container div
`
$('your-container-div').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
`

Comment: still doesnt work! i have added ` $('#signupForm,#loginForm').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();}); `

Comment: try add `$('your-pop-up').find('input').click(function(e){e.stopPeopagaion();});`

to select every input inside your pop-up

Comment: still the same..i tried with my div, and with my form id in 'your-pop-up'

Comment: $('signupForm').find('input').bind('click focus',function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
this have to work;

Comment: I have found what was wrong. I need to do this: $("body").on('click',"#signupForm, #loginForm",function (e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use Color Box Plugin from  [Link](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'/>
        <title>Pop Up</title>
        <style>
            #joinUs{cursor:pointer; color:#0066CC}
            #invite{cursor:pointer; color:#0066CC}
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $("#joinUs").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%", href:"#joinusLogin"});
                $("#invite").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%", href:"#inviteNowSignup"});

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="joinUs">Join us!</div>
<div id="invite">Invite Now</div>  

<div style='display:none'>
<div id="inviteNowSignup">
    <div id="backgroundSignup"></div>
    </a>
    <form id="signupForm">
        <input id="signupFormFields" type="email" name="email" placeholder=" E-mail"><br />
        <input id="signupFormFields" type="text" name="name" placeholder=" Password"><br />
        <input id="signupFormFields" type="text" name="subject" placeholder=" User Name"><br />
        <input id="submitSignup" type="submit" value="SIGN UP">
    </form>

    <div id="alreadyMember">
        Already a member? Log in here.
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div style='display:none'>
<div id="joinusLogin">
    <div id="backgroundJoinus"></div>
    </a>
    <form id="loginForm">
        <input id="loginFormFields" type="email" name="email" placeholder=" E-mail"><br />
        <input id="loginFormFields" type="text" name="name" placeholder=" Password"><br />
        <input id="submitLogin" type="submit" value="LOG IN">
    </form>

    <div id="signupNow">
        Don't have an account yet? Sign up here.
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```